# Is Python 2.7 "wide-build" usc4 not compatible with certain libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, pycrypto

I required the ability to work with some unicode characters with high values, so I re-installed Python 2.7.10 with option `--enable-unicode=ucs4 --prefix` ("wide-build").

I then started getting the following error:

```
...
    from Crypto.Cipher import _ARC4
ImportError: /home/fast/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString
```

I realized that `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString` must be because of the new build, so I then tried reinstalling everything fresh (new Python and new pip and newly installed libraries). I still had the same errors.

Is it simply not possible to use the `Crypto` library with Python wide-build?

I could not find any documentation on this. Are there any known work-arounds?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I seemed to have resolved the issue by manually downloading the latest copies of the libraries that were failing and running `python setup.py install`. I had to do it one-by-one until there were no more errors. I don't think this is the "answer", as this should be possible through pip, right? I would still appreciate advice on how to solve this without having to manually install the libs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no satisfactory solution for this problem in Python 2: the UCS2 and UCS4 builds have incompatible ABIs, and require libraries to be built from source (as most binary eggs are built against the default UCS2 ABI). [This issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue8654) details the problem, and the resolution that made it into Python 3.3 ([PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/)).

Your rationale for using a UCS4 build is a little suspect, though. A UCS2 build of Python is perfectly capable of "work[ing] with some unicode characters with high values", using surrogate pairs to represent supplementary code points.

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate if you point me to a description this surrogate pairs work-around. I am using ranges in a regular expression, and need to essentially do this: `re.sub(u'[\U0001d300-\U0001d356]', "", "")` (although that is just one many examples). Under a narrow build, that gives me a `sre_constants.error: bad character range`. If you know of a work-around where I could continue using Python narrow-build please let me know.

Comment: Try matching the surrogate pair sequence for the range, so `[\U0001D300-\U0001D356]` becomes `[\uD834-\uD834][\uDF00-\uDF56]`.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to convert to the surrogate pair sequence inside python? (These values are coming from a config file so I might start with something like this: `<range from="0x1D300" to="0x1D356" />`)

Comment: Python doesn't expose a function to do it, but the calculation is quite simple: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-4