# Getting Import Error for _ARC4.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have configured my django with apache and all the configurations seems to be ok.
Ubuntu system 14.04(server).
While i am getting the import error as shown in below.

Please help to sort out issue.

```
**Django Version:   1.10.7
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_ARC4.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/ARC4.py in <module>, line 66
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python**
```

Comment: You should consider using a virtualenv and/or installing a version of Python separate from the distro-provided Python.

Comment: Can u please elaborate and suggest.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644056/is-python-2-7-wide-build-usc4-not-compatible-with-certain-libraries